# How to display multiple rtmp streams from Gryphon nginx?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp, onvif

**CONTEXT :**

-I received a rtsp stream link from an onvif ip camera.

-The camera can only host 5 streaming connection at a time (I want/need more connections).

-I've been informed that a combination of ffmpeg (to convert the rtsp stream to rtmp) and nginx (to redistribute as many streams as I want) would do what I want.

-I'm on Windows 10.

-I downloaded ffmpeg from [this](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) source and nginx from [this](http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/download/) source (nginx 1.7.11.3 Gryphon.zip).

-Here's the conf file of the nginx server:

```
user nobody;
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
}
```

-I'm using this command to push my camera's stream to the nginx server:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "rtsp://user:password123@192.168.10.116:554/videoMain" -an -f flv -rtmp_live live "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live"`

-I can then see the output stream using vlc's open network stream tool (rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live)

**QUESTION :**

Is there a way to have multiple input/outout streams at the same time?

I want to have multiple cameras redirected at the same time by one server...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was fairly simple, all I needed to do was to add a second server tag in my nginx.conf file :

```
user nobody;
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;
                max_streams 512;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
        server {
                listen 1936;
                chunk_size 4096;
                max_streams 512;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
}
```

I can now push another rtmp stream to the port 1936 using:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "rtsp://user:password123@192.168.10.116:554/videoMain" -an -f flv -rtmp_live live "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1936/live"
```

Comment: Any way to do this on same port? If I am building something like Twitch, I have limited port numbers. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @RandString Maybe set the same port in the conf file? I wish I could help you out with that, but I don't have a clue.

Comment: @RandString I asked ChatGPT the following question: how does twitch work for viewers if the servers have limited ports to transmit data?
And got the following answer: Twitch uses a protocol called Real-Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP) to transmit data between the streamer’s computer and Twitch servers1. The RTMP protocol uses ports 1935 and 443 to transmit data1. Twitch uses a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to distribute video streams to viewers1. The CDN consists of multiple servers located around the world that are responsible for delivering video streams to viewers1.

Comment: Thanks for trying!
If I end up solving this, I will reply here